# Error while trying to run react-native-vision-camera on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

The codes run fine on android, but prompts an error whenever I try to run it on my iOS simulator. I hope I can get some help as soon as possible. The error I get is below:

CompileC /Users/tobiabass11/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlindSightedLite-chveemzfngmuxvhcrxjuxchmwaeg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VisionCamera.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FrameProcessorRuntimeManager.o /Users/tobiabass11/BlindSightedLite/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/ios/Frame\ Processor/FrameProcessorRuntimeManager.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'VisionCamera' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

I have tried following the troubleshooting instructions on the react-native-vision-camera page